# Why is my graphql nested query returning null?

Tags: graphql, relayjs

I'm new to graphql running into issue with nested queries and need help passing an id to identify a relationship.

### Queries

[image]

Above you can see the `PERFORMED_FOR_Affiliation` is null, though it is defined in the schema as an `Affiliation` type.

```
type Query {
      affiliations(affn_id: ID!): [Affiliation]
      performances(pfrm_id: ID!): [Performance]
      PERFORMED_FOR_Affiliation(affn_id: ID!): Affiliation
      Performance_PERFORMED_FOR(pfrm_id: ID!): [Performance]
    }
```

`PERFORMED_FOR_Affiliation` query is similar to  `affiliations` query only the relationship should return only 1 affiliation (with a matching uid).

[image]

I assume affn_id is not being passed down correctly and not sure how to do that properly. Does the PERFORMED_FOR_Affiliation need its own schema?

### Schema

```
type Performance {
    pfrm_id: ID!
    mark: Int
    affn_id: ID!
    PERFORMED_FOR_Affiliation: Affiliation
}

type Affiliation {
    affn_id: ID!
    name: String
    Performance_PERFORMED_FOR: [Performance]
}
```

I've seen some schemas that use 'nodes' and 'edge' types. As I have many other relationships would that be a better way to define the graph?

### Resolvers

```
import performances from './mockData/performances.js';
import affiliations from './mockData/affiliations.js';

export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    affiliations: (root, args) => {
      return affiliations;
    },
    performances: (root, args) => {
      return performances;
    },
    PERFORMED_FOR_Affiliation: (root, args) => {
      return affiliations;
    },
    Performance_PERFORMED_FOR: (root, args) => {
      return performances;
    },
  },
};
```

### MockData

```
//affiliations.js
module.exports = [
  {
    "affn_id": "43700F3BE17145399924AC176EACBEF4",
    "name": "Richmond Senior"
  },
  {
    "affn_id": "8BDE709AC757416082950B1BEED0CE0A",
    "name": "Cedar City"
  },
  {
    "affn_id": "123D201BB17545E3B6ECCCCB5FC61FA3",
    "name": "Delta"
  }
]
```

and

```
// performances.js
module.exports = [
  {
    pfrm_id: "6BD41C6B1C4B43D199DE42A4A408DF1A",
    mark: 1270000,
    affn_id: "43700F3BE17145399924AC176EACBEF4",
  },
  {
    pfrm_id: "EA2FBC6AB891460EA557F5B60984AD8A",
    mark: 1422400,
    affn_id: "8BDE709AC757416082950B1BEED0CE0A",
  },
  {
    pfrm_id: "54A6EEB9552C49AC9F7A87E68AC272A2",
    mark: 1422400,
    affn_id: "123D201BB17545E3B6ECCCCB5FC61FA3",
  },
]
```

Comment: Looks correct. Could you provide the query resolver?

Comment: I'm assuming the parent query will filter out the matching `affn_id` from the array of affiliations. Sounds like I'm probably returning the wrong query then?

Comment: Yes i think you have to explicitly find the affiliations with `affn_id`.

Comment: Should I implement that in the resolver, an object schema, or in the graphiql query? I tried adding  `PERFORMED_FOR_Affiliation(affn_id: ID, pfrm_id: ID): Affiliation` in my files and query with no luck.

Comment: Is it intended that in Performance `affn_id` is of type `String` while in Affiliation it is of type `ID`? Also could you provide what is in `./mockData/affiliations.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should implement that in your resolver. I guess you will have a database in the background, e.g. `mongoose`:

You query for the performances and therein you `populate` the affiliations

```js
performances: (root, args) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    performanceModel.find() // find all performances
      .populate("PERFORMED_FOR_Affiliation") // add values for affiliates
      .exec((error, performances) => {
        if (!error) {
          resolve(performances); // resolve correct object
        } else {
          reject(error);
        }
      });
  });
},
```

Comment: Thanks @Locco0_0 I do intend to switch over to my db using mongoose but currently just using an raw array to test.